# Encountering 403 Error When Directly Accessing NextJS Pages on S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

**Issue Description**
I'm encountering a 403 error when accessing pages directly in my NextJS application hosted on S3. For example, 'www.website.com/about'. The website is deployed using AWS CDK with AWS S3, CloudFront OAI, and Route53. The domain was purchased through AWS Route53 (for simplification, we will say it's called [www.website.com](http://www.website.com)).

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Attempt to access a page directly by entering the URL in the browser (e.g., [www.website.com/about](http://www.website.com/about)). Results in 403.

Note: accessing the website via [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) works. Also, from [www.website.com](http://www.website.com), using links to navigate to other pages (e.g., [www.website.com/about](http://www.website.com/about), [www.website.com/contact](http://www.website.com/contact), [www.website.com/services](http://www.website.com/services)) works.

**Expected Behavior**
I expect to be able to access pages directly without encountering a 403 error.

**Error**

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>asdfsafsaddfs</RequestId>
<HostId>sfsdfsdfsdfdssdfsdfdsffsdf</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Question**
Why am I experiencing a 403 error when attempting to access pages directly in my NextJS application hosted on S3?

**Infrastructure Overview**

- Domain: [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) (AWS Route53).
- Deployment: AWS S3 + CloudFront OAI + Route53.
- Deployment Tool: AWS CDK.
- NextJS Routing type: Pages Router.
- Issue: 403 error when accessing pages directly.

NextJS package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.153",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.18",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "depcheck": "^1.4.7",
    "next": "^14.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0"
  }
```

next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ["source.imagewebsite.com"],
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  output: "export",
  trailingSlash: true,
};
```

bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.website.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Update: I added the following CloudFront Function:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;
    
    // Check whether the URI is missing a file name.
    if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri += 'index.html';
    } 
    // Check whether the URI is missing a file extension.
    else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri += '/index.html';
    }

    return request;
}
```

Then, I attached the function to my distribution cache behavior.

This seemed to resolve the issue, and now I can successfully directly reach [www.website.com/about](http://www.website.com/about), [www.website.com/contact](http://www.website.com/contact), [www.website.com/services](http://www.website.com/services), etc.

Comment: If you specify an OAI is because you want to allow traffic to S3 only from CloudFront